# How can I get common types in the array

Tags: typescript

I have the structure

```
interface T1<T extends string> {
    path: T,
    handler: (value: T) => void
};
```

if I use a function with the same interface I don't have any problems with types, everything is correct

```
declare function foo1<T extends string>({ path, handler }: T1<T>): void

const handlerWithoutError = (v: 'some_path') => { }
foo1({ path: 'some_path', handler: handlerWithoutError })

const handlerWithError = (v: 'wrong_path') => { }
foo1({ path: 'other_path', handler: handlerWithError })
```

but if I try using an array instead of an obvious interface the type works in the wrong way

```
declare function boo1<T extends string>(arr: T1<T>[]): void

boo1([
    { path: 'some_path', handler: handlerWithoutError },
    { path: 'other_path', handler: handlerWithError },
])
```

I need the parameter of the "handler" function to match the "path" for each item of the array separately. For the second item it should be an error while the first isn't one.
How to fix that problem and force TS to show correct tips ?
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.3&ssl=19&ssc=3&pln=14&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoEYA8rkQB6QgAmAzsiWFKAOYB8yA3gLABQy7yADnGABYBcaADSsOyXnGIAbaIIAUANzhSArhEGoAlMgC89BQHtgRVgF8A3K1ZEICKXCgoYKkAjDADIZDAMGsOfEJSckoaWjkGLh5eIXFJIhkoZFMNf1pNQUNjKxYETwo46WgAdWA+AxUwAFEoKAMknWRFQQByEgMAWwgAfW4+Fu09RmTWHz8IqL5W9q7e6JbYiSKoQSWEkrLeCura+uTNHLyQArXE0r4auoamhVaAdzqQajn+wfpI01HfdAm+gWQWgY+NAXrwFoV1isIWdNpc9qYDixrLZ7I5vC43B4vAAjb7YXAECDEMgUKhPcIOKEYbC0ADaAF0MsgsiYkSxceNaaIOJE-tNOj0-uDTrJoRtypU4UlTCI2DzJv9AcCoKDhfFEqt1eLeFLkrLGUA)

Comment: Assuming `extends string` is right.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w1AEKw) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that you use the following call signature:

```
declare function boo1<T extends string[]>(
  arr: [...{ [I in keyof T]: T1<T[I]> }]
): void
```

The function is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type parameter `T` corresponding to the [*tuple*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of type arguments in `foo1()`.  Then `arr` is of the [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) `{[I in keyof T]: T1<T[I]> }` which transforms the `T` into a version where each element is wrapped with `T1<>`.  Well, mostly of that type; it's wrapped in the [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) `[...`+`]` to give the compiler a hint that you'd like to infer `arr`'s type as a tuple and not as an unordered array of arbitrary length.

Let's see what happens when you call it:

```
declare const x: T1<"a">;
declare const y: T1<"b">;
declare const z: T1<"c">;
boo1([x, y, z]); // okay
// function boo1<["a", "b", "c"]>(arr: [T1<"a">, T1<"b">, T1<"c">]): void
```

The argument `arr` is `[x, y, z]`.  This is inferred to be of the tuple type `[T1<"a">, T1<"b">, T1<"c">]` (because of the variadic tuple `[...`+`]` in the call signature; compare to what happens if you don't use tha).  Then the compiler is able to infer `T` from the mapped type `{ [I in keyof T]: T1<T[I]> }` to be `["a", "b", "c"]`.  And given that inference, the call type-checks successfully.

Let's see what happens when you call it in error:

```
boo1([
    { path: 'some_path', handler: handlerWithoutError }, // okay
    { path: 'other_path', handler: handlerWithError }, // error!
    // -----------------> ~~~~~~~
    // Type '"other_path"' is not assignable to type '"wrong_path"'.
])
// function boo1<["some_path", "other_path"]>(
//   arr: [T1<"some_path">, T1<"other_path">]): void
```

Here the compiler infers `T` to be `["some_path", "other_path"]` from the `path` properties.  Which means that `arr` should be of type `[T1<"some_path">, T1<"other_path">]`. The first element of `arr` is of type `T1<"some_path">`, but the second element is *not* of type `T1<"other_path">`, and so you get the desired error.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.3#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAIAqBGAPJ9GAD1ggBMBndCqOSAcwD50BvUdD9ABySgAsAXFgA07TnyTkANvCEAKAG5IpAVxhDMASnQBeZgoD2YMqAC+AblCgyMFFKRwMCFRBRQwBiOgQGDeAsSklNS0DIxyLNy8fMLoEtLw6KYa-oyaQobGViAonjRxkmQycADqYPwAonBwBnC66IpCAOQA7jUQ9AD6PPxN2nqsSaA+fhFR-M0UBgC2MN3RTbHxRbIFCaXlfFU1daaa2bkQ+cvFZfwGKlDbtfWN6E1Ts-O9-cyRpsO+2GM9gvePc1+izWKzgQhO8DOfAuV2qNz22RsdgcThcbg8XgARl98IQSDByFQaHQOgBtAC64QcYPQpIAdAzIqSAJLoSDoADWMAAngYEFhySl8CzKUlyel0JkTCBrLZ7I50Id8kQhQAiJCqxiWEBI+UYJVQdDctWYzXa3UoxV5Q0ALzVKDNoGxo1JRFi3NiNvF5nQAHpfegDBykNzQP7vGj3J50M68KT1arYqrTUmHZS5NShKScLgE4xYjnk5qC3hVQ7GOKMkZpU6vnJSWIOJFfpMZoCFktCsVwV3IZsYdddrFw0GQ43Bi37gZ+PBnnxgRCaYuoYOksOA-AdgBCcfhgC0B8PR+PB+YAD8L5ez7uA5huVwME1VdO+LPfqqmmyqBBp+gkBQKDAegICQTEZHQKADAg+9H1VNpPC6d8mjpUBxTDANnFcKMsRxeMATnRN0GfGc4AI9N0M4TNaULfD33zLBSxfN9ok1StJWrUAgA)